# BigQuery with lots of small files and job limits

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a large number of small files that I want to load into a single table in BigQuery. I would love to have a cloud function that loads them into Big Query when they get uploaded to a GCS bucket. Right now it's only a handful per day (say 10), but it could grow to thousands and I assume I would smack into the 1500 daily jobs limit. I don't want to use streaming because there's no business need for it relative to the expense. Is there any way to do this without performing a periodic batch load?

Comment: Is using external tables in BigQuery an option for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BigQuery DTS to watch GCS location and load new files automatically: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/cloud-storage-transfer-overview

Comment: This is just what I was looking for! Thanks!!